# Unable to access localhost with https in Angular Universal application

Tags: angular, https, angular-universal

I added Angular Universal to my existing application and I'm trying to run it with https. This is what i tried in my *server.ts* file:

```
function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4300;
  const privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('ssl/key.pem', 'utf8');
  const certificate = fs.readFileSync('ssl/certificate.pem', 'utf8');
  const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
  const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
  httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on https://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}
```

Then I run my application as follows:

```
"build:ssr": "ng build --prod --aot && gzipper --verbose ./dist && ng run project:server:production"
"serve:ssr": "node dist/project/server/main.js",
```

But when I navigate to https://localhost:port it gives me a status on pending and nothing shows.

Comment: Does it work without https?

Comment: Yes, it does. It works fine without it

Comment: and no error in the server side console?

Comment: nope, no errors at all

Comment: Can confirm that this is an issue, working on a solution

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have to call `app()`:

```js
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app());
```

I hope this solves your issue!