# Host Angular Universal website through HTTPS

Tags: node.js, angular, express, iis

I have an Angular Universal app that was published to IIS and ran through iisnode. When running on http it is working fine, but when running on https it is returning a Cloudflare Error 520 "Web server is returning an unknown error".

Meaning if I navigate to "http://example.com" it is working fine, but if I navigate to "https://example.com" I get the above mentioned error.

Below is my server.ts file, where I tried to change some configurations as mentioned on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60772374/unable-to-access-localhost-with-https-in-angular-universal-application). However, Cloudflare does not provide a private key so I couldn't follow through, and now I am stuck and I have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync, readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { createServer } from 'https';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/projectName/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  ////////// HTTPS Test Server /////////////
  // const privateKey  = readFileSync('ssl/project.pem', 'utf8');
  // const certificate = readFileSync('ssl/project.crt', 'utf8');
  // const credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
  // const httpsServer = createServer(credentials, app());

  // httpsServer.listen(port, () => {
  //   console.log(`Node Express server listening on https://localhost:${port}`);
  // });
  ////////////  END   ///////////////

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}
```

Comment: A quick workaround while further investigating 520 errors is to either make the record DNS-only in the Cloudflare DNS app or temporarily pause Cloudflare, contact your hosting provider or site administrator and request a review of your origin web server error logs.

Comment: Is your server is accessible over HTTPS outside of Cloudflare ??

Comment: No, it is not accessible

Comment: First up, try an openssl connect to the https url, to see what kind of cert you get (If any) and what protocol is negotiated.  From memory, something like "openssl s_client -connect example.com:443"   (Assuming your server is listening on the standard SSL port 443)

Comment: Does your server have a firewall? Could you check the firewall rules? If it doesn't have 443 allowed, move this over to serverfault.com, those guys can help you out. If it is not a server-level issue but rather it is an application-level issue, can you please dig around logs and post what you find?

Comment: The server is a joint server, so there are other websites hosted their as well and they all are running fine. It's just this website that's built using Angular Universal which is why its causing a huge headache

Comment: Make sure your DNS settings are set correctly for your site's domain. The steps involved to check your settings depends on your DNS host. If your hosting plan has DNS bundled with it, then check with your hosting provider.